# strange behavior in PHP function: timezone_name_from_abbr

Tags: php

echo timezone_name_from_abbr("", 3600*7, 0); //ok
echo timezone_name_from_abbr("", 3600*8, 0); //NOT ok! return nothing!
echo timezone_name_from_abbr("", 3600*9, 0); //ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a known bug: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44780

3600*8 = 28800 is actually in the list of offsets that do not work for PHP
5.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to bee a know bug of this function : if you search on php's bugtracker, you'll find this report : [#44780      some time zone offsets not recognized by timezone_name_from_abbr](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44780)

This report corresponds exactly to the bug you are having.

There is a patch, but the bug itself is not marked as solved yet... and it is still present in PHP 5.3.1-dev